# Fullcalendar how to remove resource?

Tags: fullcalendar

I want allow user to add or remove resources from calendar. currently it is possible to add or remove events from calendar.

Currently i am removing all the events and reloading the calendar.
any better option i don't want o close the page and open it again

I have check the documentation https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-remove

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `refetchResources`, but how you handle it and how you can change data to change the resources is pending to you.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/refetchResources

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources');
```

Comment: it will fetch all resources i am looking for, if i have A, B, C,D resources and i just want to remove B from calendar and replace it with E. in other words remove B and add E

Comment: I had the same issue, I use the function to get resources data, and each time to apply the new resources the calendar should rebuild.